# Table TD Rowspan Not Working With Ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

please see if you can help me.
Code:

```
            var th_table = $('#table-id');
            $(data).each(function (index, th) {

                html = '<tbody>'
                    + '<tr>'
                    + '<td rowspan="2" class="text-left">' + th.MONTHNAME + '</td>'
                    + '<td class="text-left">' + th.CATEGORY + '</td>'
                    + '<td class="text-left">' + th.NOOFDAYS + '</td>'
                    + '</tr>'
                    + '</tbody>';
                th_table.append(html);
            });
```

Result

```
Month   Category   Days
Jan     CAT1       2
Jan     CAT2       3
Jan     CAT3       1
Feb     CAT1       2
Feb     CAT2       3
Mar     CAT3       1
```

my desired output

```
Month   Category   Days
Jan     CAT1       2
        CAT2       3
        CAT3       1
Feb     CAT1       2
        CAT2       3
Mar     CAT3       1
```

but rowspan was not recognize by ajax... please help

Comment: Take a look to the renderized output(html), your issue is not related to ajax

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Just make a Right click to your web page and take a look to the source, how many tbody do you see?

Comment: Another problem: `<tbody>` shouldn't be in the loop.

Comment: The issue is relative to table, not ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code as below:

```
var th_table = $('#table-id');
var tmpMonth;
$(data).each(function (index, th) {
   var html = '';
   if (tmpMonth !== th.MONTHNAME) {
      html = '<tr>'
           + '<td rowspan="2" class="text-left">' + th.MONTHNAME + '</td>'
           + '<td class="text-left">' + th.CATEGORY + '</td>'
           + '<td class="text-left">' + th.NOOFDAYS + '</td>'
           + '</tr>';   
      tmpMonth = th.MONTHNAME;
   } else {
      html = '<tr>'
           + '<td class="text-left">' + th.CATEGORY + '</td>'
           + '<td class="text-left">' + th.NOOFDAYS + '</td>'
           + '</tr>';  
   }

   th_table.append(html);
});
```

Note that the **data** MUST be sorted by **MONTHNAME**.

Or group your **data** by **MONTHNAME** and loop the grouped result.

```
var groupedResult = _.groupBy(data, function(d) { return d.MONTHNAME; });
_.forEach(groupedResult, funcation(values, key) {
  // key is your MONTHNAME
  // values is an array
  html = '<tr>'
           + '<td rowspan="' + values.length + '" class="text-left">' + values[0].MONTHNAME + '</td>'
           + '<td class="text-left">' + values[0].CATEGORY + '</td>'
           + '<td class="text-left">' + values[0].NOOFDAYS + '</td>'
           + '</tr>';   
  th_table.append(html);

  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++ ){
    html = '<tr>'
           + '<td class="text-left">' + values[i].CATEGORY + '</td>'
           + '<td class="text-left">' + values[i].NOOFDAYS + '</td>'
           + '</tr>';   
    th_table.append(html);
  }

});
```

Comment: how about the dynamic rowspan?

Comment: You can use **lodash** to group data and loop it.  I will update my answer later.